# Generating results joining two classes in EF5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

In my project I have two classes `ProductCategory` and `Product`.

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

In my UI, there is an form to create products under categories. The form includes 2 ComboBoxes. One for product ID and one for Category (Value member - category id, display member - category name). And another text box for product name. And a ListView for displaying products with their category names.

My question is; I want to retrieve an object collection that includes these fields (to display in the ListView).

```
ProductID, ProductName, CategoryID, CategoryName
```

Please tell me the right way to this thing.

Thanks.

Comment: try to google, "linq to entity join":)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *projection* with `Select`:

```
var objects = context.Products
    .Select(p => new
    {
        ProductId = p.ProductId,
        ProductName = p.ProductName,
        CategoryId = p.CategoryId,
        CategoryName = p.ProductCategory.CategoryName
    })
    .ToList();
```